# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting 11

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    spiral = open('spiral.txt', 'r') # open input text file
    dim = spiral.readline() # read first line of text
    print(dim)
    if (dim % 2 == 0): # check to see if even
        dim += 1 # make odd
```

I know this is probably very obvious but I can't figure out what is going on. I am reading a file that simply has one number and checking to see if it is even. I know it is being read correctly because it prints out `10` when I call it to print `dim`. But then it says:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

for the line in which I am testing to see if dim is even. I'm sure it's basic but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

The `readline` method of file objects always returns a string; it will not convert the number into an integer for you.  You need to do this explicitly:

```
dim = int(spiral.readline())
```

Otherwise, `dim` will be a string and doing `dim % 2` will cause Python to try to perform string formatting with `2` as an argument:

```
>>> '10' % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>>
```

Also, doing `print(dim)` outputed `10` instead of `'10'` because `print` automatically removes the apostrophes when printing:

```
>>> print('10')
10
>>>
```